# a simple 3 level flex layout with bottom right alignment

Tags: css, html, layout, svg, flexbox

I need to make a flexible header which takes the calculated height of the svg logo and takes the available width to fit the nav:

layout1: i.stack.imgur.com/Oa8gB.png

If there is not enough space to fit all nav buttons (a) in one row next to the svg, the nav block needs to move under the svg and take the full width of the canvas:

layout2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2avAA.png

Very important that the nav block aligns to the bottom right corner of the parent header element.

I read, googled, tried en read more... but no satisfying result. Any suggestions with flexbox? No js please, like to keep it pure.

**Edit:**
This is what I tried: http://codepen.io/Kleajmp/pen/dYEeKW

**html:**

```
<header> 
      <div id="logo" class="col-3"><img src="http://www.dsunits.be/v4/img/DS_units.svg"></div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">DS units</a>
    <a href="#">button2</a>
    <a href="#">button3</a>
    <a href="#">button4</a>
    <a href="#">button5</a>
    <a href="#">button6</a>
    <a href="#">button7</a>
    <a href="#">button8</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**css:**

```
header{ display:flex; align-items:flex-end; justify-content:space-between; }
div#logo{ display:inline-flex; align-items:flex-start; width:25%; }
div#logo img{ max-height:150px; }
nav{ display:inline-flex; cursor:pointer;  }
nav a{ display:inline-flex; flex-wrap:nowrap; }
nav a:hover{ color:white; background-color:#0099cc; border-top-right-radius:0.5rem; }
```

Comment: Whatever code you've tried should be a part of your question. Stack Overflow is a question and answer service, not a code-authoring service. Here's are some guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, I putted a link to codepen with what I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...I'm not entirely sure how this is supposed to work but I think this is close to what you are after.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div#logo img {
  height: 150px;
}
nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: plum;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  line-height: 1rem;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0099cc;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://www.dsunits.be/v4/img/DS_units.svg">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">DS units</a>
    <a href="#">button2</a>
    <a href="#">button3</a>
    <a href="#">button4</a>
    <a href="#">button5</a>
    <a href="#">button6</a>
    <a href="#">button7</a>
    <a href="#">button8</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YybmvQ)